# If you create all your images assets out of one PNG; via different divs. Can you then resize these assets?

Tags: html, css, png, background-image

I am working with an animation. This animation uses ONE `png` for all of its image assets. The divs are sized to fit one of the assets from the Image. Then the `background-position` is adjusted to perfectly line the `background-image` asset inside the `div`. This is practice I see used quite often.

**My question is:** Is there a way to re-size these elements to fit their div? Say I wanted to make the assets smaller. Is that possible?

I have been trying to find a solution for a while.. I am open to anything as long as it doesnt require me to re-code my entire animation. I appreciate any help given!

**Here is an example i've created for the problem:**

***Image Asset:***

[image]

***Code Snippet***

```css
body{font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;color:#0f7eca;text-indent:60px;}

.wb_Assets{
    position:absolute;
    background:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLfyH.png) no-repeat 0px 0px;
    display:inline-block;
    left:60px;
    }
  
#Test1{
    width:204px;
    height:200px;
    }
  
#Test2{
    width:204px;
    height:200px;
    background-position:-210px 0px;
    margin: 120px 0 0 220px;
    transform: rotate(25deg)
    }
  
#Test3{
    width:204px;
    height:200px;
    background-position:-420px 0px;
    margin: 20px 0 0 467px;
    }
```

```html
<h3> THE 3 EXAMPLES BELOW SHARE SAME THE EXACT IMAGE ASSET</h3>

<br><br>

<div id="Test1" class="wb_Assets"></div>
<div id="Test2" class="wb_Assets"></div>
<div id="Test3" class="wb_Assets"></div>
```

**[HERE IS A JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/jqax1hgr/2/)** *~Although you may just click "Run Code Snippet BTN above"*

**THANK YOU!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can scale the element.

```
#Test2{
    width:204px;
    height:200px;
    background-position:-210px 0px;
    margin: 120px 0 0 220px;
    transform: rotate(25deg) scale(0.7);   // >> Add scale()
}
```

---

[Example on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jqax1hgr/3/)

Comment: OMG a scale attribute?? I had no idea.. Wow! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Some possibilities:

- Use the `background-size` property to resize the background image to fit the new dimensions.
- Scale the `div` with CSS transforms, e.g. `transform:scale(.7)`.